# Accessing Fragment in FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a FragmentActivity with a FragmentTabHost. I add fragments to the tabs using the following:

```
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(tab1Name).setIndicator(tabIndicator2),
            EventSettingsStep1Fragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(tab2Name).setIndicator(tabIndicator3),
            EventSettingsStep2Fragment.class, null);
```

I can't figure out how to access the instance of EventSettingsStep1Fragment.

I tried the following but I'm getting null:

```
EventSettingsStep1Fragment fragment1 = (EventSettingsStep1Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tab1Name);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where do u wish to create an instance of ur fragment? is it inside fragment activity?

Comment: Yes. Inside the FragmentActivity